# Plant for cat to eat that she won't vomit?

Tags: cats, plants

My cat eats from all the decoration plants in the house, and then vomits them.

What common inexpensive plant can a cat eat that's healthy and that she won't throw up?

And it's a plus if it's a pretty-enough plant that it makes the house look nice.

Thanks.

Comment: Flummox's answer provides the info you need in terms of what plants are "safe" for your cat to eat - but to address the other part of your question re: vomiting this is actually the *intended* outcome of when cats eat plants. They do so in order to allow them to regurgitate things like hairballs.

Answer (score 5):

### [Chlorophytum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophytum)

for one. There are [more, way more.](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/cats-plant-list) But this one is quite safe, or as safe as green stuff is going to be for carnivores.

And then there is "[cat grass](https://www.petmd.com/cat/care/evr_ct_how-to-grow-cat-grass)". That seems to be a combination of grasses, mainly green and tender new growth.

---

**Why do cats vomit?** And why do they eat plants?

I have no better answers then the wikipedia article on [cat & nutrition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#Nutrition). Let me quote the relevant part:

> Cats do eat grass occasionally. A proposed explanation is that cats use grass as a source of folic acid. Another is that it is used to supply dietary fiber, helping the cat defecate more easily and expel parasites and other harmful material through feces and vomit.

Answer (score 2):

The only plant I know of that cats eat without vomiting is catnip [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catnip). This plant might grow quite large, but it can be cut and held at the size you want in your house. It is good for this plant to be cut and held at 10-20 cm, as it will grow denser by doing this.

I always have this plant in my house for my cat to nibble on or rub against, but it has a fairly strong but not unpleasant smell.